# C# WPF element position not in correct place

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I'm developing a vision processing application using WPF and EmguCV 3.0. My issue is that the element isn't positioned correctly on-screen. I have viewed what the padding is, and it returns all sides as 0. The ImageBox element from Emgu, which is what I am using to display the images, is encapsulated in a Windows Forms Host control. I have two other ImageBox elements, which display properly. Each of the ImageBox elements are within their own tab in a TabControl. On startup, I set the width and height properties of all the ImageBoxes and their canvases.

An additional thing to note is that the other two ImageBoxes also overflow out of their boundaries, but are reset back into the boundaries after switching back and forth between the tabs. This only happens once.

Here is a link to screenshots of what the UI looks like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMX0.jpg

Additionally, here is the XAML and C# code for the ImageBoxes.

```
<TabItem x:Name="ImageTabControlHSV">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="HSV" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Canvas x:Name="HSVImageCanvas">
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <emui:ImageBox x:Name="HSVImageBox"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Canvas>
</TabItem>

//Width and height properties are gotten from camera image.
HSVImageBox.Width = ratioWidth;
HSVImageBox.Height = ratioHeight;
HSVImageCanvas.Width = width;
HSVImageCanvas.Height = height;
HSVImageCanvas.MaxHeight = height;
HSVImageCanvas.MaxWidth = width;
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Putting a counter for how many times the problematic ImageBox has been selected and using Canvas.SetTop() and Canvas.SetLeft() seems to be a workaround. I would still like to know why the canvas is changing its position.

Comment: is it possible to use a grid container instead of a canvas?

Comment: Try set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment. `<Canvas x:Name="HSVImageCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">`

Comment: @alex10 Thank you for the suggestion! However, it did not seem to fix it. The post has been updated with new information though.

Comment: @failedprogramming Thank you for the suggestion! I tried putting the canvas into a grid container, but no such luck. The original post has been updated though.

Answer (score 0):

You might try performing a Canvas.SetTop(HSVImageCanvas, HSVImageCanvas.Top) and Canvas.SetLeft(HSVImageCanvas, HSVImageCanvas.Left).

Doug